# How to remove this kind of element in the Map using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
function Stream() {
  let subscriber = new Map();

  return {
      subscribe: function(method) {
        if(typeof method === 'function') {
          subscriber.set(method);
        }
        else
          throw new Error('Pass a valid method.');
      },
      push: function(val) {
        [...subscriber].forEach(([method]) => method(val));
      },
      unsubscribe: function(method) {
        console.log(subscriber.has([method]));
        console.log([method]);
        [...subscriber].forEach(([method]) => console.log([method]));
        if (typeof method === 'function' && subscriber){
          subscriber.delete([method]);
        }
        [...subscriber].forEach(([method]) => console.log([method]));
      }
  };
}

var stream = new Stream();
stream.subscribe((val)=>console.log(val*1));
stream.subscribe((val)=>console.log(val*2));
stream.subscribe((val)=>console.log(val*3));

stream.push(2);
stream.push(3);
stream.unsubscribe((val)=>console.log(val*3));
stream.push(4);
```

In the unsubscibe function, which shows up that "subscriber.has([method]) " returns false to me, but after I print the method out and compare with in side of the subscriber map, which looks the same. Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: `[method]` creates a new array (with one element) each time, so it's never in the map.

Comment: You're missing the second argument to `.set()`.

Comment: `stream.unsubscribe((val)=>console.log(val*3))` will never match anything anyway. Two arrow functions, even if equivalent logic, will never be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have two main problems.

First, the argument to `.has()` should just be `method`, not `[method]`. The keys `subscribers` are just functions, not arrays. All the places where you wrote `[method]` should not be in an array.

Second, you need to use named functions. Two functions with the same source code are not actually equal, so `.has()` won't be able to match them.

You should be using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) rather than `Map`, since you're not associating any values with the functions. And there's no need to use `[...subscriber]`, both `Map` and `Set` have `forEach` methods that iterate over the elements.

```
console.log(((val)=>console.log(val*3)) == ((val)=>console.log(val*3)))
```

will log `false`.

```js
function Stream() {
  let subscriber = new Set();

  return {
      subscribe: function(method) {
        if(typeof method === 'function') {
          subscriber.add(method);
        }
        else
          throw new Error('Pass a valid method.');
      },
      push: function(val) {
        subscriber.forEach((method) => method(val));
      },
      unsubscribe: function(method) {
        console.log(subscriber.has(method));
        console.log(method);
        subscriber.forEach((method) => console.log(method));
        if (typeof method === 'function' && subscriber){
          subscriber.delete(method);
        }
        subscriber.forEach((method) => console.log(method));
      }
  };
}

var stream = new Stream();
const times1 = (val)=>console.log(val*1);
stream.subscribe(times1);
const times2 = (val)=>console.log(val*2);
stream.subscribe(times2);
const times3 = (val)=>console.log(val*3)
stream.subscribe(times3);

stream.push(2);
stream.push(3);
stream.unsubscribe(times3);
stream.push(4);
```

Comment: I don't know, but it's in the MDN descriptions of both.

Comment: The compatibility charts for `Map.prototype.forEach` and `Set.prototype.forEach` both say it has been available since Chrome 38 and FF 25.